# Drupal 7 webform: How to change label of the field that was created by "Webform Dragndrop" module?

Tags: drupal, drag-and-drop, drupal-webform

I am using the "[Webform Dragndrop](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_dragndrop)" module to add a drag-drop field to my webform. I need to change the label as follow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZOFW.png)

I have tried form alter hook, but the label is not in the $form array.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Module **Webform Dragndrop** allows you to set `Drag and drop upload text` so you don't need to customize code.

Go to `Configuration` > `Content authoring` > `Webform dragndrop settings` and change the value to what you want:
[image]